# How to wait first request finish before start second with Rx?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have an async method `makeRequest()` with callback. It called many times from different classes of my application. I need that this calls start one by one and never simultaneously.

I want to implement this using Rx. Like this:

```
public void execute() { // This method called many times from another classes
    Observable.just(true)
        // what I need to add here?
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .map(o -> {
                    internalExecute();
                    return o;
            })
        .subscribe();
}

private void internalExecute() { // This method should called only when previous call was finished
    makeRequest(this::onRequestFinished);
}

private void onRequestFinished() {
    // here is I handle request finish
}
```

But at now all requests works at parallel. What I need to add here to run requests one by one?

Comment: does each client that initiate this call wait for the request to finish? or is it just a trigger to execute a call in a different part of the system, and the caller don't care about the result?

Comment: @yosriz Class which calls method execute waiting for result from method onRequestFinished.

Comment: so each client execute some arbitrary request and waits for the its dedicated result without any relation to a different request other client might execute?

Comment: Yes. But I need that all of this requests run one by one (wait for previous).

Comment: got it, why are you not returning Observable to the clients at execute? do you really want your request to run on mainThread (that's what will happen in your code)?

Comment: makeRequest() is async method. I don't know, what I get if I will use Observable. Could you please to explain it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147544/discussion-between-yosriz-and-bartwell).

Answer (score 1):

According to comments, you have here separated streams and requests. each client that execute request expect a result from the request. but no requests allowed to run in parallel, in this case I think the easiest way is to limit the `Scheduler` to an application global background sequential thread Executor, i.e:

```
Schedulers.from(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
```

provide somewhere in your app this single thread Executor, in singleton manner  of course, it's important that each request stream will use the same object:

```
private final Scheduler singleThreadScheduler = Schedulers.from(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());

public void execute() { // This method called many times from another classes
    Observable.just(true)
            .map(o -> {
                internalExecute();
                return o;
            })
            .subscribeOn(singleThreadScheduler)
            .subscribe();
}

private void internalExecute() { // This method should called only when previous call was finished
    makeRequest(this::onRequestFinished);
}

private void onRequestFinished() {
    //NOTE: you should make sure that the callback execute where you need it (main thread?)

    // here is I handle request finish
}
```

besides that, you're not exposing `Observable` outside, to the clients, but rather using callback mechanism, you can leverage reactive approach further, by making `execute()` returning `Observable`. (and enjoy composition of `Obesrvable`s, operators, proper use of `observeOn`/`subscribeOn`, error handling with `onError`, disposing/unsubscribing etc.), as you're using async api, you can use `fromEmitter()`/`create()` (in newer RxJava1 version)), read more [here](https://medium.com/yammer-engineering/converting-callback-async-calls-to-rxjava-ebc68bde583):

```
 private final Scheduler singleThreadScheduler = Schedulers.from(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());

public Observable<Result> execute() { // This method called many times from another classes
    return Observable.fromEmitter(new Action1<Emitter<? extends Object>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Emitter<?> emitter) {
            emitter.setCancellation(() -> {
                //cancel request on unsubscribing
            });
            makeRequest(result -> {
                emitter.onNext(result);
            });
        }
    })
            .subscribeOn(singleThreadScheduler)
}
```